# Image preview in MFMailComposeViewController is blank

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, xamarin.ios

In my iOS app, I allow the user to select an image from a photo album or capture one from the camera. Immediately after that, I present an MFMailComposeViewController with the selected/captured image as an attachment.

The image is attached and sent correctly, but the photo thumbnail preview area of the email is blank in all cases **except when the most recent photo from the album is selected**. If an image is captured or an old image is chosen from an album, it is blank like this:

[image: screenshot]

My code to attach the captured/selected image is:

```
MFMailComposeViewController email = new MFMailComposeViewController ();
email.SetToRecipients(new string[] {"test@test.com"});
email.SetSubject("Photo for " + CurrentCompany.DbaName + " (" + CurrentCompany.CoKey.ToString() + ")");

//imageToEmail is a UIImage that is set in the callback from the image capture/selection process
email.AddAttachmentData (imageToEmail.AsPNG(), "image/png", "photo.png");

email.Finished += HandleFinished;
NavigationController.PresentViewController(email, true, null);
```

Why is the preview blank?

Comment: Advice: Stop using Monotouch and go native.

Comment: I do not think the issue is in the code you're showing. Can you edit your question to show how to retrieve `imageToEmail` and how it get to the code above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs across this in the future, I tried several different ways of saving the UIImage (app's personal storage location, photo album, etc.), but none of the different ways worked for attaching the image as a PNG. Saving the UIImage as a JPEG is what fixed it for me. Changing this line:

```
email.AddAttachmentData (imageToEmail.AsPNG(), "image/png", "photo.png");
```

to:

```
email.AddAttachmentData (imageToEmail.AsJPEG(), "image/jpg", "photo.jpg");
```

allowed all captured or selected images to display the preview thumbnail in the email.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    email.AddAttachmentData (imageToEmail.AsPNG(), "image/png", "photo.png");
```

Raplace this line to :

```
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToEmail);//Your uiimage convert to nsdata
    [email addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Myphoto"];
```

Comment: Replacing C# code with Objective-C code in MonoTouch isn't what I'm looking for